# Need to find build version

Tags: buildfire

Reposting again .I am using Buildfire to develop my iOS app. I need to find a build version from react code and also wanted to check if app is currently on Test Flight or App Store

Answer (score -1):

The question is not super clear to me but I'll do my best to answer:

> Build version from react code

BuildFire create the builds on their servers so if you're referring to building react native code you have as an app that will not work. If you're referring to building a plugin using BuildFire platform in react, you can start with http://sdk.buildfire.com and https://github.com/BuildFire/reactPluginTemplate.git

> App currently on Test Flight or App Store

If you have a paid plan and published your app you should receive an email to confirm whenever it gets published to the App Store and you can also search for it in the App Store. Also if you are the owner of the iOS developer account you can use Test Flight for builds submitted by BuildFire.

If you don't have any paid plans and want to test your app or plugin you can view it in https://apps.apple.com/us/app/buildfire/id1592380675